# Getting value from API

Tags: php, json

How can I get a certain value from the following API result:

```js
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "prices" : [
            {
                "market_hash_name": "Glock-18 | Catacombs (Minimal Wear)",
                "price": "0.08"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to extract the price value which in this case is 0.08 and put it in the variable $lowest_price. This is the code I came up with:

```php
$obj = json_decode($json);
if($obj->{'status'} == "fail") die("notfound");
$lowest_price = $obj->data->prices->price;
$lowest_price = (float)($lowest_price);
```

Thanks.

Comment: enter the json code here, not the image

Comment: Do you get any error? Something not working as intended?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: is it not `$obj['status']` and `$obj['data']['prices']['price']`?

Comment: @VijayaSankarN It's not an associative array. the array starts at prices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have it:

```
$lowest_price = $obj->data->prices[0]->price
```

Comment: @bogdanb Then check your json string, because it might not be what you showed in your pic.

Comment: How can I verify if it actually gets it... The database isn't updating any value..

Comment: Can you add me on skype and discuss about this cause I can't seem to make it work: bagdasar.bogdan   I am willing to pay for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
if($obj->{'status'} == "fail") die("notfound");
$lowest_price = $obj->{'data'}->{'prices'};

//$lowest_price is now an array
// for multiple values:
foreach($lowest_price as $value)
{
    $price = (float)$value->{'price'};
}

// For a single value:
$price = (float)$lowest_price[0]->{'price'};
```

Comment: You dont need the `{}` around the object properties.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I usually add them to visually differentiate the traversal in my code easily

Comment: You're overwriting the price value on each iteration, if the array has multiple prices you get the last, if the array won't have multiple prices you don't need a loop

Comment: @DamienPirsy It is unclear what he wants to do with the value, that's why i added the comment (for multiple value) therefore is he has multiple values in his json Object, he can handle each and every one of them